# Escaping quotes in SPARQL

Tags: character-encoding, sparql, iri

How do I escape quotes in this SPARQL query?

```
SELECT * WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andre_\"Dede\"_Sabino> rdfs:label ?lbl . ?sub a foaf:Person . ?sub rdfs:label ?lbl . optional {?sub dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .} optional {?sub dbo:birthPlace ?birthPlace . ?birthPlace a dbo:Location } optional {?sub dbo:birthPlace ?birthPlace2 .} ?sub dbo:abstract ?abstract . filter(langMatches(lang(?lbl), "en")) filter(langMatches(lang(?abstract ), "en")) } LIMIT 10
```

I have tried `""` and `\"` and `'`.

Comment: by the way, at at least in public English DBpedia there is no such entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote character (`"`) is not allowed in IRIs (in general, not just specifically in SPARQL). It has to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) as `%22`.

So the IRI would not be

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andre_"Dede"_Sabino
```

but

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Andre_%22Dede%22_Sabino
```

(Browsers typically *display* the unencoded form of the IRI in the address bar, but when copy-pasting it, you should get the percent-encoded form.)

---

If you need a quote character inside a string value in SPARQL, you can encode it with a backslash:

```
?person schema:name "Andre \"Dede\" Sabino" .
```